# Prefill update form from record saved in text file

Tags: php

I have an Add form that takes `name, email, phone` and saves it to a contacts.txt file.

I have another form that takes in a `name` and if the `name` is found in the contacts.txt file, an update form that's identical to the add form should appear.

My question is, if the search is found, how do I prefill the update form fields with the `name, email, phone` that is linked to the name?

Example add form:

```
Name: John
Email: abc@xyz.com
Phone: 1234567890
```

Search form:

```
Enter a name: John
```

Update form:

```
Name: John
Email: abc@xyz.com
Phone: 1234567890
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already searched the text file, and from the results set the `$name`, `$email`, and `$phone` variables. Prefilling the form fields would look something like this:

```
<form action="">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo isset($name) ? $name : ''; ?>"><br>
Email:<br>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($email) ? $email : ''; ?>"><br><br>
Phone:<br>
<input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo isset($phone) ? $phone : ''; ?>"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

If the variable is set it will display it, if it is not then it won't.

Comment: Hmm how would I have access to the email and phone variables if I'm only searching by the name variable? My search form submits to a processSearch php file and from there if the search is found an update.php form page is displayed by an include statement.

Comment: You have those variables saved in the contacts.txt. So when you search by `name` from the search form you might want to also grab the email and phone fields from the text file  too. Then when you display the update form use the values that you just got. Just because you are only searching by name does not mean you cant get other lines from the text file!

Comment: I kind of understand how you say the other variables are also stored in the txt.file, but I'm still a little confused. In the search form, I enter a name so I can use $name = $_POST['name'];, but if I never prompt for a phone or email how can I catch those too?